# how do i round numbers in a column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, rounding, tidyverse

How do I round the numbers to 2 decimal points within a column within a dataframe?

The name of the df is tax_data and the column that I want to round is called rate_percent

I tried using:

```
format(round(rate_percent ,2), nsmall =2) but this didn't work.
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Here is a `tidyverse` option to replace the values in the rate_percent column with the rounded version.
`tax_data %>% mutate(rate_percent = round(rate_percent, 2))`

Answer (score 6):

Here, in Base-R

```
tax_data$rate_percent <- round(tax_data$rate_percent, 2)
```